# jeditable accidentally triggering on Draggable on nested items

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jeditable

I'm using jquery-ui's draggable for drag-and-drop, and [jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) for inline editing.

When I drag and drop an element that's also editable, right after it's dropped jeditable kicks in and pops into 'edit mode'.

How can I disable this behavior?

**Edit** - the problem happens because of netsting - see [this example](http://jsbin.com/izaje3/5). I also added draggable to the mix to make the example more realistic (the actual real problem is in [this site](http://kuzando.com) that I'm working on)

**Note** - even though this question has an accepted answer because of the bounty rules, the problem is still not resolved for me.

Comment: I read the title has "jedi table"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATED 2:** use children()

**DEMO 2:** http://jsbin.com/izaje3/2

in responce to your comment

```
$(function() {
    $('.editable').editable();
    $('.draggable').draggable({
        drag: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).children('div').removeClass('editable')
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {
           $(this).children('div').addClass('editable')
        }
    });
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsbin.com/ihojo/2

```
$(function() {
    $(".draggable").draggable({
        drag: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).unbind('editable')
        }
    });
    $(".editable").editable();
});
```

OR you can do like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.editable').editable();
    $('.draggable').draggable({
        drag: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).removeClass('editable')
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).addClass('editable')
        }
    });
});
```

Assuming you have something like this:

```
<div class="draggable editable"></div>
```

**NOTE:** just for sake, you can also take advantage by using the handle method!

> http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#handle

Comment: Looks like your demo is working, cool !

I haven't yet integrated your solution to my own code base, I'll accept this as soon as I have.

Comment: sure i have tested it in all win browsers! ;) in anycase try it local cause jsbin sometimes suck with some browser!

Comment: There seems to be some other problem with my code - see this example that works, although I am no longer unbinding the  method: 
http://jsbin.com/ihojo/23

Comment: The problem I'm having is because of nesting - it's not the same elements that's editable and draggable: http://jsbin.com/izaje3

Comment: Sorry to be a bother, but when I tried to apply to my code I'm still not getting it to work :(

I don't understand why your example works in the first place - by the time you call $(this).removeClass('editable'), jQuery already added the hooks, so it's now "too late".

Here is my non-working example: http://jsbin.com/izaje3/5
I updated my example a

Answer (score 3):

I found this post because I came across this exact problem (nested jEditable inside a jQuery UI Draggable) today; while I don't think my solution is particularly elegant I felt like I ought to share it in case someone else has the same problem.

Instead of trying to unbind and reinitialize the jEditable on the drag events (which seems to fire the click event AFTER the reinitialization on stop()), I found it easier to set the jEditable to use a custom event which is only triggered on mouseup if the draggable wasn't dragged (simulating a click).

The anonymous function as the first argument of editable should be replaced with the url you're POSTing to if that's your thing.

http://jsbin.com/izaje3/13

```
var notdragged = true;
$('.editable').editable(function(value, settings) {
        return value;
    }, {event : 'custom_event'
});
$('.draggable').draggable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
        notdragged = false;
    }
});

$('.editable').bind('mousedown', function() {
    notdragged = true;
}).bind('mouseup', function() {
    if (notdragged) {
        $(this).trigger("custom_event");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

oftomh, you should try and get a hold of the `Event` object within the drop handler, and then try to call `event.preventDefault()`, `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` or `event.stopPropagation()`

luckily for you you're on jQuery. Doing so cross-browserly with vanilla JS is annoying.

Comment: It appears the problem doesn't happen when the dragabble and editable are the same object (see @aSeptik's answer). Here is a live example of my problem: http://jsbin.com/izaje3

Answer (score 0):

Ripper,

One possible workaround is to use the double click event for your jEditable component.

To do this, just initialize the jEditable object with the following option:

```
event: 'dblclick'
```

Comment: This defeats the purpose, I absolutely need the trigger to be a single click.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting contenteditable="false" on these items.
Just try adding this attribute in the relevant html tag and see what happend.